# Communication between PHP and C++

Tags: php, c++, json, command-line, parameters

I want to communicate PHP and C++ code.

I need to pass a big JSON between them.
The problem is that I am currently using "passthru", but for some reason I do not know, the C ++ code does not receive the entire parameter, but is cut in 528 characters when the JSON is 3156.

By performing tests, I have been able to verify that the "passthru" command supports as many characters as 3156. But I do not know if there is a maximum input parameter size in C ++.

The PHP application is as follows:

```
passthru('programc++.exe '.$bigJSON, $returnVal);
```

The C++ application:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  char *json = argv[1];
}
```

Is there any way to fix the problem? I have read about PHP extensions and IPC protocols, but the problem is that I have to do a multiplatform program (I must have a version for Windows, another for Linux and for Mac). And I think that using PHP extensions and IPC protocols (as far as I could read) complicates things quite a bit.

Comment: Is `$bigJSON` [escaped](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) properly? If it contains an unescaped space at around character 528 it could become the second argument for your C++ application.

Comment: Instead of passing it as argument I would use input output streams using [proc-open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)

Comment: I tried to use "escapeshellarg", the problem is that in windows, "espaceshellarg" removes the double quotes from the JSON. And the JSON interpreter in C ++ needs them =(

Comment: check `argc` if it's bigger than 2 then the parameter sent is received as multiple parameters in `main`

Comment: Many thanks! I have solved it using "proc_open". I edit the question with the solution.

Comment: @AdriaCiurana **don't do that!** don't include answers in the question. If you want you can add an answer to your own question, or you can request the user who gave you the answer in a comment to put it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
The solution is use "proc_open" and use the pipe stdin and stdout. In my case, I use the library rapidjson. I add double quotes in PHP in order to rapidJSON works and process the JSON.
PHP:

```
$exe_command = 'program.exe';

$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout -> we use this
    2 => array("pipe", "w")   // stderr 
);

$process = proc_open($exe_command, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
$returnValue = null;
if (is_resource($process)){
    fwrite($pipes[0], $bigJSON);
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    $returnValue = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
}
```

C++:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    std::string json;
    std::getline (std::cin, json);
    cout << json << endl; // The JSON
}
```